# Optimizing seating chart

Tags: excel, vba

How complicated is this? I am using an excel userform to take RSVP for a dinner event. Each table seats 10. When a reservation is taken, they have the option to give up to 4 other names to be seated with any of those families. I want to automate Excel to optimally seat everyone without having many empty seats at each table taking in account their preferred seating requests. Also as each family is seated, their name comes off the list to avoid seating them at another table also. Can this be done with code and to add a twist have some graphical representation of the seating plan.

I haven't tried anything because I dont even know where to start and I am faily new to coding. Im using Excel 365.

Comment: The challenge with this is not the actual writing of the code but working out the logic. If you don't have much experience with VBA coding, this may not be the best scenario to get started.

Comment: Can someone help me with the vba?

Comment: Yes, someone will, as soon as you post what VBA you have come up with so far. We'll help you learn, not write the code for you.

Comment: Something similar is covered in Practical Management Science by Albright & Wilson - uses the solver...

Comment: Gentlemen, sorry for the absence. I dont know where to start with this code, I could show you my code for the actual reservation userforms but thats not what you need.Please get me started and I think I might be able to get most of it afterwards. I hope.